# Vite not prepending base path to anything in public directory

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a simple Vite project using React and TypeScript. The deployment target is GitLab pages. The GitLab pages URL is like so: `https://<username>.gitlab.io/<projectname>` so in `vite.config.ts` I have to set `base: "/<projectname>/"` like so:

`vite.config.ts`

```
import { build, defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/vite-ts-test/" // <---------- base set here
})
```

(my project is called `vite-ts-test` as shown above)

Everything works (the base URL is prepended to everything) except for anything in my root projects `/public` directory for static assets.

For example, I have `vite.svg` (the vite logo) stored in `/public` as a static asset and when built and previewed (`npm run build && npm run preview`) I get this (here's a snippet):
(note: lines numbered for clarity)

```
1 <div>
2     <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
3         <img src="/vite.svg" class="logo" alt="Vite logo">
4     </a>
5     <a href="https://reactjs.org" target="_blank">
6         <img src="/vite-ts-test/assets/react.35ef61ed.svg" class="logo react" alt="React logo">
7     </a>
8 </div>
```

The problem is line 3 in the `img` tag `src` attribute, it says `/vite.svg` when the actual path is `/vite-ts-test/vite.svg`.
Line 6 gets it right, however this is not a static asset and isn't in `/public` in my project.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you end up solving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a duplicate question as an issue on the Vite GitHub: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7358

Basically you have to import the image (or whatever static asset) manually.

```
import viteImg from "/vite.svg"

function App() {
  return (
      <img src={viteImg} className="App-Logo" alt="Logo">
  )
}
```

...instead of...

````
function App() {
  return (
      <img src="/vite.svg" className="App-Logo" alt="Logo">
  )
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

path: /public/images/somepic.jpg

I use this in Vite Vue.

```
<img :src="'images/somepic.jpg'" alt="">
```

I think in React it should look like this.

```
<img src={'images/somepic.jpg'} alt="">
```